# Do you "rent with" a landlord or a housemate?

Tags: meaning

> I rented with Jane for 5 years

Does this mean Jane is a co-tenant or a landlord?

Comment: We *usually* rent ***from*** a landlord, and ***with*** a co-tenant. But sometimes people will say they rent with a landlord (especially if "the landlord" is a large national chain of letting agents, for example, rather than a single individual). Apparently, [***Purplebricks** is by far and away the largest single estate agency brand in the UK*](https://propertyindustryeye.com/eye-exclusive-new-league-table-shows-purplebricks-easily-biggest-agency-brand-and-connells-ahead-of-countrywide/), so *I rent **with*** (also ***through***) *Purplebricks* would both be perfectly acceptable usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's great and more than enough for an answer

Comment: If only there were ngrams-for-meaning.....

Answer (score 1):

You rent 1313 Mockingbird Lane *from* your landlord.

You rent 1313 Mockingbird Lane *with* your roommate Jane.

Your example would most likely mean Jane was your roommate but there are some people who might use *rent with* instead of *rent from* to describe Jane as being your landlord.  As it stands in your example, it is not entirely clear who Jane is.  The sentence is most clearly expressed by including your relationship to Jane, either roommate or landlord.

Although *with* is the preposition to use for roommates, I doubt I would use it to describe the situation.  I would be much more likely to say, *Jane and I rent 1313....* and not use any preposition.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say "Do you rent with a landlord or housemate" you either rent or own a home. The more appropriate thing to say here would be "Do you rent or own your apartment/house", "Do you have your own place", "Do you share an apartment/house with other people?"

**To rent** definition by Google (verb):
*pay someone for the use of (something, typically property, land, or a car).*

**"they rented a house together in Spain"**

As you can see from the definition **"to rent"** with someone would mean to collectively pay rent for the use of a property. If you rented a house **with** Jane that means she was your roommate and not your landlord, however, if you rented a house **from** Jane that means Jane is your landlord and you're paying her rent (in this case she doesn't live in the property with you, you pay her to live in her property).

Comment: Your last paragraph approaches an answer to my question, but it's not obvious to me why that's implied by the definition, and are you sure that's the only way that this phrasal verb is understood?

Comment: I hope I made myself clear this time :)